# Validate Controls in an asp.net (VB) panel which contain a specific css class

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, validation

I have a lot of controls on my asp.net web form that require validation. Rather than list each control in the code behind page that requires validating I would like to add the css class "required" to the necessary controls and then on submit the code behind will validate each control with this class. I'm fairly new to .net so here is some ***Pseudo code***:

```
Public Sub ValidateAllControls(ByVal a As Object)
        For Each c As Control In a.Controls
            If c.Controls.Count > 0 And c.Controls.class = "required" Then
                ValidateAllControls(c)
            Else
                If TypeOf c Is TextBox Then
                    If CType(c, TextBox).Text = "" Then
                        c.Controls.BorderColor = Drawing.Color.Red
                        lblValidate.text = "Text Box cannot be empty"
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
```

Happy to hear your suggestions. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. This works how I wanted it to:

```
Public Sub ValidateAllControls(ByVal a As Object, FormControl As Control)
        For Each c As Control In a.Controls
            If c.Controls.Count > 0 Then
                ValidateAllControls(c, FormControl)
            Else
                If TypeOf c Is TextBox Then
                    Dim tb As TextBox = CType(c, TextBox)
                    If tb.ToolTip = "required" And tb.Text.Length = 0 Then
                        tb.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Red
                        tb.BorderColor = Drawing.Color.Black
                        tb.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Solid
                        tb.BorderWidth = "1"
                        Dim lbl As Label = FormControl.FindControl("lblvalidate")
                        lbl.Text &= "The fields in red cannot be empty!"
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
```

Call: `ValidateAllControls(Me, Me)` on your Submit button and make sure you add the `ToolTip="required"` to your control. Hope this helps.